# br on enter div editable database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

So I've got this *div* I am able to edit like this:

```
if(isset($user_id)){
?>
    <h2 id="title" onclick="makeEditable(this)" onblur="makeReadOnly(this)"><?php echo $out['title'];?></h2>

    <div id="text_div" onclick="makeEditable(this)" onblur="makeReadOnly(this)">
    <?php echo $out['text_html'];?>
    </div>
    <a class="button button1 logout" href="login/logout.php">Uitloggen</a>
<?php
}
```

which goes to a *ajax* call function which inserts the *new* data into the database.

**ajax call**

```
    var title = $('#title').text();
var text = $('#text_div').text();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'insert_text.php',
    data: {
        text: text,
        title:title
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Successsfull');
        if(data.success) {
            console.log(data);
            // window.location.href = "loginForm.php";
        } else {
            console.log('no succes');
        }
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

also got this function ripped off some other topic here on SO

```
$('#text_div').keydown(function(e) {
// trap the return key being pressed
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
  // insert 2 br tags (if only one br tag is inserted the cursor won't go to the next line)
  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
  // prevent the default behaviour of return key pressed
  return false;
}
});
```

this works properly but *how* do I set this `<br />` tags in the database. At the moment it correctly does it in the browser, but when I *refresh* it puts everything behind each other.

For example I got:

`test<br />test`
it displays it on edititing like : 
`test`
`test`

which is correct but when I *insert* it in the database with the *ajax* call and refresh the page it displays it like: 
`test test`

any sugestions on how I can solve this?

Comment: Before you insert sth in db you probably use some cleaning function eg **strip_tags**

Comment: Problem is that at `var text = $('#text_div').text(); ` it already removes all the `<br>` and just displays a plain string of `testtesttesttest` @nospor

Comment: Ah, right, I didnt notice that text(). So you know the solution. Just use .html() instead of .text() :)